# OutOfRangeError : RandomShuffleQueue : Working with tensorflow's shuffle_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use [string_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) for a filename of my `tfrecord` as an input of `tf.TFRecordReader` and feed it into `tf.train.shuffle_batch` to make batches of my custom data.
Then I create a session, model, etc and 'tf.train.coordinater.'

**It worked well during the first iteration of the data, but it stops working at the 2nd iteration.**

Say, I have 10,000 rows of data and set the batch size to 100. After 100 training loops, I got this error:

> OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue
>   '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient
>   elements (requested 100, current size 0)

I set `num_epochs` of [string_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) to `None`, so I thought `string_input_producer` would feed the same filename again once tf.train.shuffle_batch run out of data.

Am I missing something??

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# queue with a list of filenames 
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], name="filename_queue", 
                                                      shuffle=True, num_epochs=None) 
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue) 
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
          features={
                'f1': ....
                'f2': ....,
          })

# batch
batch_size = 100
f1_batch, f1_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([f1, f2], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=10,
                                              capacity=1000 + 3*batch_size,
                                              min_after_dequeue=1000) 

# 
# ... create a session, build model, optimizer, summary writer etc
# 

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)    

# start queue thread
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS): 
    # get batch data    
    x, y = sess.run([f1_batch, f2_batch])        

    # optimize
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:x,y:y})

    # ... calc loss, write summary ...
```

Comment: It's a bit odd to use session.run() to evaluate the queue output, then pass the evaluated values into the rest of the model (usually you'd keep them as Tensors the whole way). Do you get the same error if you just print x and y at each step rather than optimizing? It also looks like there's a typo with "f1_batch, f1_batch" on the shuffle_batch line.

Comment: Thank you, Allen.  Yes I got the same error if I just print `x` and `y`.  

I thought I need to `session.run()` to get python values, so that I can feed them into `feed_dict`. Am I missing something?  and yes, that `f1_batch, f1_batch` is a typo. thanks!

Comment: The idiomatic way to feed queue output into a model would be to define the model in a function which takes the data as Tensor inputs. This is what tf.learn does, using a [model_fn to define an Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard3/tf.contrib.learn.Estimator.md). As for the error: I haven't been able to reproduce it. Could you try turning it into a complete (i.e. executable) and hopefully minimal example?

Comment: It seems like there was some issue in my `tfrecord` file. After I rebuild the file, everything started working well (magically somehow)...  As for feed queue, you are right. I can define the model with tensor inputs. I haven't thought about it.  Thanks again for your help. much appreciated!!

Comment: It turned out... it works well if the number of total sample data in the `tfrecord` file is divisible by the batch size. I guess it is related to `allow_smaller_final_batch` flag of `tf.train.shuffle_batch`.  I thought if I set False to the flag, then the function just ignores the remaining "smaller final batch" and skip to the next iteration. If this isn't the case, does it mean I always have to pay attention to the number of samples/batch size?

Comment: That's my understanding of `allow_smaller_final_batch`. What is the behavior difference between the divisible and indivisible case? Just performance, or are you getting an error?

Comment: I got an error something like this:  
`OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 24)`

this case I have 10024 total samples and batch size 100.

Comment: Happy to take a look if you can reproduce that in an example I can run.

Comment: I got this error when I switched from directly feeding tensors to my graph to using placeholders, evaluating the tensors first before adding them to the feed_dict. I guess it just doesn't work for input queues.

Answer (score 0):

when following the official instruction of using `tfrecord`, `OutOfRangeError` often comes from inadequate elements in the queue or inappropriate data construction or pre-procession.

BTW, I have two problems. 1, insteading of using `feed_dict`, I want to know how to define the model in a function which takes the data as Tensor inputs. In this case, I have to construct seperate computation graphs to feed training data as well as testing data. 2, if using `feed_dict`, how do you know the end of an epoch? It seems that `tf.train.shuffle_batch` will output fixed-length batches until the end. It's hard for me use `epoch`(not `batch` number) to control the training process.